# Azure function running multiple times for the same service bus queue message

Tags: c#, azure, singleton, azureservicebus, azure-functions

I have an Azure function (based on the new C# functions instead of the old .csx functions) that is triggered whenever a message comes into an Azure Service Bus Queue. Once the function is triggered, it starts processing the service bus message. It decodes the message, reads a bunch of databases, updates a bunch of others, etc... This can take upwards of 30 minutes at times.

Since, this is not a time sensitive process, 30 minutes or even 60 minutes is not an issue. The problem is that in the meanwhile, Azure Function seems to kick in again and picks up the same message again and again and reprocesses it. This is an issue and cause problems in our business logic.

So, the question is, can we force the Azure function to run in a singleton mode? Or if that's not possible, how do we change the polling interval?

Comment: Was your Function App created under the App Service Plan or Consumption Plan?  

Under App Service Plan, make sure that AlwaysOn is turned on.  Under the Consumption Plan, the Function App is terminated after 5 minutes (configurable to extend to 10 minutes, see "functionTimeout" value at https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/host.json), which may explain the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: I have the App Service Plan. My function is not terminating. In fact, the opposite is happening. Multiple functions are processing the message.

Comment: @Yasir Even I faced the same issue, as it was processing multiple message in parallel it was creating duplicate records in upsert. I managed to handle it by making the `maxConcurrentCalls` to *1*. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75898239/3057246 for more details.

Answer (score 6):

`AutoRenewTimeout` is not as great as suggested. It has a downside that you need to be aware of. It's [not a guaranteed operation](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/azure-service-bus-autorenewtimeout). Being a client side initiated operation, it **can** and sometimes **will** fail, leaving you in the same state as you are today.

What you could do to address it is to review your design. If you have a long running process, then you process the message, and hand off processing to something that can run longer than `MaxLockDuration`. The fact that your function is taking so long, indicates you have a long running process. Messaging is not designed for that.

One of the potential solutions would be to get a message, register processing intent in a storage table. Have another storage table triggered function to kick-off processing that could take X minutes. Mark it as a singleton. By doing so, you'll be processing your messages in parallel, writing "request for long running processing" into storage table, completing Service Bus messaging and therefore not triggering their re-processing. With the long running processing you can decide how to handle failure cases.

Hope that helps.

Comment: When you say "Mark it as a singleton", what is the it you are referring to? And how do I mark it as a singleton?

Comment: The other storage table triggered function. I've implemented somewhat similar process with NServiceBus and Service Bus. You'll find the code and the diagram here: https://docs.particular.net/samples/azure/azure-service-bus-long-running/ With functions approach, your long running Function (Processor) doesn't have to poll, it would be triggered.

Comment: I'd suggest using the https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension, which provides the long-running / orchestration capabilities you need

Comment: Matt, durable Functions are not there yet in terms of maturity.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is related to Service Bus setting...

What is happening is that the message is added to the queue, the message is then given to the function and a lock is placed on that message so that no other consumer can see/process that message while you have a lock on it.

If within that lock period you do not tell service bus that you've processed the file, or to extend the lock, the lock is removed from the message and it will become visible to other services that will then process that message, which is what you are seeing.

Fortunately, Azure Functions can automatically renew the lock for you. In the `host.json` file there is an `autoRenewTimeout` setting that specifies for how long you want Azure Functions to keep on renewing the lock for.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/host.json

```
"serviceBus": {
  // the maximum duration within which the message lock will be renewed automatically.
  "autoRenewTimeout": "00:05:00"
},
```

Answer (score 2):

So your question is on how to make the Azure Function Message trigger to process one message at a time, and a message has to be processed once only.

I have been able to achieve the same functionality using the following `host.json` configuration.

```
{
  "serviceBus": {
    "maxConcurrentCalls": 1,
    "autoRenewTimeout": "23:59:59",
    "autoComplete": true
  }
}
```

Note that I set the `autoRenewTimeout` to 24 hour, which is long enough for a really long running process. Otherwise you can change it to a duration that fits your need.

Many will argue the suitability of using Azure Function for a long running operation. But that is not the question that needs an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I also experience the same issue, what I did is remove the default rule and add a custom rule on subscriber.

```
(OriginalTopic='name-of-topic' AND OriginalSubscription='name-of-subcription-sub') OR (NOT Exists([OriginalTopic]))
```

Answer (score 0):

### `Message Lock Duration` and `Max Delivery Count`

There is something called as `Message Lock Duration` and `Max Delivery Count`, so as per the config below it will be locked by the client for 5 minutes to be processed once the timeout happens it will cause an inner exception and will try to redeliver it incrementing the delivery count and up to the `Max Delivery Count` as below 10.

[image]

Scan the log and If this is happening due to the `Lock Duration Timeout` you can either try to manually renew it using [BrokeredMessage.RenewLock Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.renewlock?view=azure-dotnet) in your code or automatically with [OnMessageOptions.AutoRenewTimeout Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.onmessageoptions.autorenewtimeout?view=azure-dotnet#microsoft-servicebus-messaging-onmessageoptions-autorenewtimeout)

---

### Function `Auto Scaling`

You can also disable `Auto Scaling` by making it to **1** which is by default **200**, but this will have no/little effect to `ServiceBus Triggerd Function` since even with a single instance it will make concurrent calls to `service bus` to read message.

[image]

---

### Singleton

Now for your answer you can try [Singalton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#singleton) but I think even with `singleton` if the function scales out it will be multiple `singleton` as the function is not in a single box with a single instance. It might work in other triggers but not with `service bus trigger`.

---

### `maxConcurrentCalls` in `host.json`

If your issue is not because of `Message Lock Duration` it might be because of `concurrent` calls to service bus which is by default **32**. So you can add [the following](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp#hostjson-settings) to your `host.json` and minimize the values to **1** to test with outcome.

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
        "serviceBus": {
            "prefetchCount": 100,
            "messageHandlerOptions": {
                "autoComplete": true,
                "maxConcurrentCalls": 32,
                "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:05:00"
            },
            "sessionHandlerOptions": {
                "autoComplete": false,
                "messageWaitTimeout": "00:00:30",
                "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:55:00",
                "maxConcurrentSessions": 16
            },
            "batchOptions": {
                "maxMessageCount": 1000,
                "operationTimeout": "00:01:00",
                "autoComplete": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But if you just what to read the message is sequence from a `ServiceBus Trigger Function` you just need to add the following in the `host.json` to tell him stop making concurrent calls. And if you log the `Sequence Number` of the message in the console you can verify it as it will now follow a sequence.

```json
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
        "maxConcurrentCalls": 1
      }
    }
  }
```

This will even avoid duplicates if you are doing `upsert` as the records are created one by one in sequence but the downside it will be slow and compromise the performance.